# What is a difference between aggfunc count and len

Tags: python, pandas

Since both `aggfunc=len` and `aggfunc='count'` returns  same results why count is surrounded in quotation and len is not?

Comment: Because `"count"` isn't a built-in function like [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len).

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted ? good question imo. @jonrsharpe you should post an answer so this can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

(The reason for quotation is addressed above.)

They do not always produce the same outcomes.
While `len` returns the length of the object, `count` returns the number of valid data points.

```
d = [
    ['a',1],
    ['a',np.nan],
    ['b',2],
    ['b',0],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['type','value'])
print(df)
print(df.groupby('type').agg(len))
print(df.groupby('type').agg('count'))
```

this returns

```
  type  value
0    a    1.0
1    a    NaN
2    b    2.0
3    b    0.0
      value
type       
a         2
b         2
      value
type       
a         1
b         2
```